# Place name google places api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-maps

I have an array of place names like 'Hazrat Nizamuddin Railway Station, New Delhi, Delhi, India' and so on. The array also contains alternative names to the above like 'Nizamuddin Railway Station, Nizamuddin East, New Delhi, India' etc. They are both the same.

I now have a variable 'reference'. I need to use the reference place string and find all the places in the array that correspond to that place.

How should i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out which elements in the array equal the *reference* variable? Is it an string just like the element in the array, or is it maybe a search query ie only part of the desired place name?

```
for (i=0; i < placeNamesArray.length; i++) {
    if (placeNamesArray[i] === reference) {
        // You now have the index you want, which is the current i.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not as simple as that. The places themselves may not be the same in the sense of a string. For example a railway station may have two different names according to google maps.